# How can I negate a predicate in XML DSL?

Tags: apache-camel

In Apache Camel, I want to negate a condition in a `<when>` using `<simple>`

```
<!-- I want to negate the simple below before the "Do something" block -->
<when>
    <simple>
        ${headers.msg[ABC]} == 'Fred' ||
        ${headers.msg[DEF]} starts with 'MO'
    </simple>

    <!-- Do something if the above is not true -->
</when>

<!-- I can achieve the above this way -->
<choice>
    <when>
        <simple>
            ${headers.msg[ABC]} == 'Fred' ||
            ${headers.msg[DEF]} starts with 'MO'
        <simple>

        <!-- do nothing -->
    </when>
    <otherwise>
        <!-- Do something -->
    </otherwise>
</choice>
```

If I could negate the first example's `<simple>` condition, then it would be simpler than the second way. Another option would be if there's a `does not start with` operator. Or does somebody have another way to do this with little code.

I can use `<groovy>` to do the first example, but we have a directive to try to use `<simple>` as much as possible in our project. We also have a directive to use XML DSL instead of Java.

Comment: You can use an regexp pattern with simple you can setup to do the predicate

Comment: Thanks Claus, I was so focused on wanting to negate the entire condition that I honestly didn't think of using a regex.